# Data Validation Won't Save

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that adds data validation to a worksheet. It appears to work:

```
Public Sub AddDataValidation(ByRef rng As Range, ParamArray options() As Variant)
    With rng.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(options, ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm trying to use this to add data validation to 40+ workbooks that I'm generating. The sub runs fine (and if I don't close the workbooks, the validation works). But, when I close the workbook and reopen, I get this warning message:

> We found a problem with some of the content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

Clicking No closes the book; clicking Yes opens it, but the data validation is not there.

What am I missing here? Is it because the validation options aren't stored in the sheet? Will it work with a different filetype?

Thanks

Comment: Could not reproduce the error, May please share code stub calling the `Sub AddDataValidation`

Comment: How large are the lists you're adding?  Are you sure it's the validation causing the problem, or could it be something else?

Comment: @TimWilliams I believe it's 12 options long. I'm not certain it's the data validation itself, but that's the only thing that seems to disappear when I try to reopen the files. Each file has ~1000 rows of data.

Comment: If you skip applying the validation do you still get an error message when opening the files?

Comment: @TimWilliams nope. Commented the validation line out and the book opened just fine. Then, I ran just the `AddDataValidation` sub on the book, closed it, opened it, and got the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your list of options is too large to handle the list as a string instead of a range. I found this one out the hard way myself as well :). If I'm not mistaken, the list can't exceed 255 characters. So if it is larger, you need to store the list in a range and refer to the range in your validation formula.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The options are fairly long. With a Range, I'm getting a different issue where the validation shows as an empty list and won't accept anything but a blank cell. I'll have to do some digging into that now.

Comment: Derp, nevermind. This works. I was applying it to the wrong range.Thanks for the help!